# unique identifier that represents unique app installation

Tags: ios, installation, uniqueidentifier

Is there a way to get a unique identifier that represents unique app installation? For example when Jon instals myApp, his uniquie identifier for this specific application is 123456. When Maria instals the same app, her identifier is 2345678. I am not looking for `identifierForVendor`, because identifierForVendor just asks for the ID of device.

Comment: If you mean can you link an install to the iTunes account that installed it, no you can't. IdentifierForVendor isn't the id of the device, it is a unique Id for your apps on a device. In your scenario are you looking the same Id if Jon installs your app on his phone and iPad?

Comment: No, ID should be differenet on ipad and iphone.

Comment: Then it sounds like `identifierForVendor` is what you are after